# How to verify ECDSA signature in ASN.1 format and public key in DER using BouncyCastle?

Tags: c#, .net-core, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I have a byte array that contains the public key, and a byte array that contains the ASN.1 formatted signature. Using ECDSA P-256.

The following code loads the public key:

```
var publicKey = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publicKeyDERBytes);
```

And the following code verifies the signature:

```
var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("ECDSA");

signer.Init(false, publicKey);
signer.BlockUpdate(signatureASN1Bytes, 0, signatureASN1Bytes.Length);
Console.WriteLine(signer.VerifySignature(signature));
```

But it always writes false. What could be wrong?

Using BouncyCastle.NetCore 1.8.3 on .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was not getting the correct signer.

Instaead of:

```
var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("ECDSA");
```

It should be:

```
var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withECDSA");
```